# What is the proper way to create a filter _GET (or _POST) variable?

Tags: php, netbeans, global-variables

Need an explanation on this..  I'm adding pagination to a website, and need a pointer on Filter Input/Escape Output.  As you can see below, the newly created `page` global defaults to page 1 when the page first loads, and this is the correct behavior, using the shorthand ternary operator.

```
$itemsPerPage = 20;
$numOfFilms = $totalRows->rows;
$numOfPages = ceil($numOfFilms / $itemsPerPage);

$filter ='page';

$getPages = isset($_GET[$filter])
   ? $_GET[$filter]
   : 1;

var_dump($getPages); // <-- Testing

$paginationOptions = [
    'options' => [
        'default'   => 1,
        'min_range' => 1,
        'max_range' => $numOfPages,
    ]
];

$pageNumberClean = trim($getPages);
$pageNumber = filter_var(
    $pageNumberClean,
    FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    $paginationOptions
);
$range  = $itemsPerPage * ($pageNumber - 1);
```

Knowing that I should never trust user input, and in turn the reason Netbeans throws a Warning:

> Do not Access the Superglobal _GET Array directly.  Use some filtering functions instead...

---

If I wrap both sides of the ternary statement in `filter_input` the warning goes away and is syntactically correct, but the page will not run, because the filtered input variable `page` doesn't exist in the _GET array, so:

- What is the accepted standard or proper way to create a _GET array variable without directly accessing the _GET array?
- In other words: Can I properly use `filter_input` and create the variable, so the warning goes away?

**Telling me to turn the warning off is not the answer I'm looking for**.

Also, note that I've googled for "How to initialize a _GET variable" and most of the results explain the difference between `$_GET` and `$_POST` which I already know.

Thanks for your time

Comment: How about this: Only accept an integer page number. "$get_pages = (isset($_GET[$filter]) && is_int($_GET[$filter])) ? $_GET[$filter] : 1;"

Comment: Also, in your code there may be an error- Should there be a '$' in front of get_pages?

Comment: @Hiphop03199 Yes, thats what I get for Copy/Paste LOL.... Fixed

Comment: If I remember correctly, using the filter functions is the only way to get Netbeans to not give that warning. I think the warning is worded a bit strongly, though. The filter functions are useful tools, but you shouldn't necessarily _have to_ use them to safely handle input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that should satisfy NetBeans, because it uses one of PHP's filter functions. As I mentioned in a comment, I would consider "is_int()" to be a safe enough check to use here as well.

```
$filtered_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$get_pages = (!empty($filtered_page)) ? $filtered_page : 1;
```

According to the PHP Docs in the following places, this will remove all non-integer characters from the GET variable. We then check to make sure the remaining string isn't empty (either blank, false, or 0).

Please note: a page number of 0 will trigger the empty, and return 1. Let me know if this is an issue.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

https://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Extra Note: You could also do this with arguments to the filter function, including a default value. That way you could do it all with two lines cleanly:

```
$filter_options = array('options'=>array('default'=>1, 'min_range'=>1, 'max_range'=>$numOfPages));

$get_pages = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $filter_options);
```

Comment: I tried adding the third condition, as you suggested above, and that works.    The warning is gone, because the middle condition satisfies the warning. Now I'll try this one as it looks more elegant, i.e i didn't think of passing the filtered input through to `$get_pages`

Comment: According to the docs, filter_input returns, "Value of the requested variable on success, FALSE if the filter fails, or NULL if the variable_name variable is not set. If the flag FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE is used, it returns FALSE if the variable is not set and NULL if the filter fails." so a better implementation would test the result against FALSE for failure or NULL to see if it is not present. Otherwise it will be an `int` based on the filter choice and zero would be valid.

Comment: I'm ok as it's written above, as my output will always start on page 1, ie malformed `?page=0` should return page 1.

Comment: Perhaps, but the empty() condition captures both NULL and EMPTY as well. If we were going for the best-est solution, we could use a default value instead. I've attached this to my answer.

Comment: I have added the array I had in my code already, which is the same one that you alluded to